# Converting an object into a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, tostring

I need to iterate over an object turn all values that are `falsey` to `"All"` and turn that Object into a string.

I thought I could use `.reduce` to replace the falsey values and that works. But I am having trouble figuring out a clean way to have the object with each key value pair as its own string separated by commas.

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false,
  d: null,
  e: 0,
  f: "Some"
};

let newObj = Object.keys(object1).reduce((acc, key) => {
    
  if(!object1[key]){
    object1[key] = "All"
  }
  
  return {...acc, [key]: object1[key]}
    
  
}, {})

console.log(Object.entries(newObj).join(":"));
```

my expected Result would be `"a: somestring, b: 42, c: All, d: All, e:All, f:Some"`

Comment: [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Comment: Im actually checking for all falsey values. Not specifically for null, i will fix that in my question. @Ivar

Comment: `JSON.stringify(newObj).slice(1,-1)`

Comment: What is even the question? It looks like you are only asking for a way to format the output, but you give us all that extra information about how you turned the objects values from null to "All"

Comment: @Koyaanis My question is how to turn an object into a string. But it is not completely straight forward `ie) JSON.stringify(object1)`  because i have to check the `falsey` values that is why I included this part.

Comment: So the answer is changing `console.log(Object.entries(newObj).join(":"));` to `JSON.stringify(newObj).slice(1,-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do something like this

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false,
  d: null,
  e: 0,
  f: "Some"
};

const string = Object.entries(object1).map(([k, v]) => `${k}: ${v? v: 'All'}`).join(',')

console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false,
  d: null,
  e: 0,
  f: "Some"
};

let newObj = Object.keys(object1).reduce((acc, key) => {
    
  if(!object1[key]){
    object1[key] = "All"
  }
  
  return {...acc, [key]: object1[key]}
    
  
}, {})
const f = JSON.stringify(newObj) 
console.log(typeof f)
```

this will print you "string" to console :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help,

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false,
  d: null,
  e: 0,
  f: "Some"
};

const objToString = Object.keys(object1)
  .reduce((prev, key, index) => prev + `${key}: ${object1[key] || "All"}, `, "")
  .slice(0, -2);

console.log(objToString);

// a: somestring, b: 42, c: All, d: All, e: All, f: Some
```

Answer (score -1):

you could write your own function to achieve this like

```js
var  toString = function(object){
  if(object instanceof Object){
  let objkeys = Object.keys(object);
  let str = "";
  for(let k of objkeys){
    object[k]= object[k]==null?"all":object[k];
      if(str!="")
      str+=", ";
      str+=k + ":" + object[k];
  }
  return str;
}
return "";
}
```

will get you the desired result